# PHP and python thrift

Tags: php, python, thrift

I am new into thrift apache. I am using the API edenremote. When thrift call the function readMessageBegin it goes into loop and i receive no response and request is going on

Please help me how to debug this issue.

@Edit: Since yesterday i debug it and found the following things.

My main code in PHP is following

```
$result = json_decode(exec('./Authenticator.py'));
    //var_dump($result);
    $socket = new TSocket('localhost', 9090);
    $socket->setSendTimeout(50);
    $socket->setRecvTimeout(50);
    $transport = new TFramedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
    $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
    $client = new \edenremotephp\pub\EdenRemote\EdenRemoteClient($protocol);
    $transport->open();
    $client->openSession($result->sessionID, 1);
```

And response in PHP is for openSession is

```
/home/abbas/www/local.edenremote.com/index.php:56:string 'TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from localhost:9090' (length=54)
```

And in server (Python) got this response

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2017 20:00:22] "POST /response HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2017 20:00:22] code 400, message Bad request version ('\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00$3633e905-28dd-11e7-a104-b4b67605b5e0\x08\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00')
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2017 20:00:22] "J�
                                        openSession
                                                   $3633e905-28dd-11e7-a104-b4b67605b5e" 400 -
```

I hope it will help you to understand my main issue. Thank you.

Python Server Handler (It is not complete, complete file is very big. If you want to know more please let me know):

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="/testData/index.html"

        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                filePath = os.path.realpath(curdir + self.path)
                print "Debug - filePath:", filePath
                f = open(filePath) 
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Handler for the POST requests
    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path=="/send":
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile, 
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
            })

            print "Your access key ID is: %s" % form["accessKeyId"].value

            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("Thanks %s !" % form["accessKeyId"].value)
            return          

        if self.path=="/authenticate":
            print "authenticate post happened"
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile, 
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
            })

            xml = self.handleServerAuthChallenge(form)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(xml)
            return          

        if self.path=="/response":
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile, 
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
            })

            xml = self.handleServerAuthResult(form)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(xml)
            return                      

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def handleServerAuthChallenge(self, form):
        global gAuthRequests
        global gDebug

        if gDebug:
            print gWebSeparator

        # Instance the XML object to return to the auth requester
        serverAuthChallenge = AuthXml.ServerAuthChallenge()

        # Make sure that the required parameters are present
        error = False
        for requiredParam in kAuthPhase1_QueryNames:
            if requiredParam not in form:
                error = True
                serverAuthChallenge.setResultCode(str(AuthResultCode.kAuthResultCode_MissingQueryParameter))
                serverAuthChallenge.setResultMessage("You must provide the following query parameter: " + requiredParam)
                if gDebug:
                    print "Missing query parameter"
                    print "  " + serverAuthChallenge.getResultMessage()
                    print

        # If all the parameters are present, then process them
        if not error:
            clientVersion = form[kAuthPhase1_QueryName_ClientVersion].value
            accessKeyId = form[kAuthPhase1_QueryName_AccessKeyId].value
            if gDebug:
                print "handleServerAuthChallenge called with these form values:"
                print "  clientVersion: " + clientVersion
                print "  accessKeyId:   " + accessKeyId
                print

            # If the client is too old, then return an error
            clientVersionInt = int(clientVersion)
            if clientVersionInt < kClientAuthVersion_Minimum:
                serverAuthChallenge.setResultCode(str(AuthResultCode.kAuthResultCode_ClientUpdateNeeded))
                serverAuthChallenge.setResultMessage("The specified client version (" + clientVersion + ") is too old to use this service. Please update your client side library to the latest version.")
            else:
                # First see if the key ID from the client is in our disabled list. If it is,
                # then return the disabled error
                if accessKeyId in gDisabledAccessKeyHelpers:
                    serverAuthChallenge.setResultCode(str(AuthResultCode.kAuthResultCode_AccessKeyDisabled))
                    serverAuthChallenge.setResultMessage("The specified " + kAuthPhase1_QueryName_AccessKeyId + " is disabled and cannot be used: " + accessKeyId)

                # See if the specified key ID from the client can be found in our test dictionary.
                # If it can't, then return an error. Otherwise, provide the challenge XML to the
                # client so that it can take the next steps.
                elif accessKeyId in gValidAccessKeyHelpers:
                    serverAuthChallenge.setNextUrl("http://" + str(TEST_SERVER_HOST_NAME) + ":" + str(PORT_NUMBER) + "/response")
                    requestId = str(uuid.uuid1())
                    authRequest = AuthRequest(accessKeyId)
                    gAuthRequests[requestId] = authRequest
                    serverAuthChallenge.setRequestId(requestId)
                    challenge = base64.b64encode(authRequest.getChallenge())
                    serverAuthChallenge.setChallenge(challenge)
                else:
                    serverAuthChallenge.setResultCode(str(AuthResultCode.kAuthResultCode_InvalidKeyIdentifier))
                    serverAuthChallenge.setResultMessage("The specified " + kAuthPhase1_QueryName_AccessKeyId + " is unknown: " + accessKeyId)

        # Get the XML string that we'll return to the caller
        xml = serverAuthChallenge.getXml()
        if gDebug:
            print "About to provide this XML response to the client:"
            print
            print serverAuthChallenge.getXml(pretty=True)

        return xml

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def handleServerAuthResult(self, form):
        global gSessions
        global gDebug

        if gDebug:
            print gWebSeparator

        # Instance the XML object to return to the auth requester
        serverAuthResult = AuthXml.ServerAuthResult()

        # Make sure that the required parameters are present
        error = False
        for requiredParam in kAuthPhase2_QueryNames:
            if requiredParam not in form:
                error = True
                serverAuthResult.setResultCode(str(AuthResultCode.kAuthResultCode_MissingQueryParameter))
                serverAuthResult.setResultMessage("You must provide the following query parameter: " + requiredParam)
                if gDebug:
                    print "Missing query parameter"
                    print "  " + serverAuthResult.getResultMessage()
                    print

        # If all the parameters are present, then process them
        if not error:
            requestId = form[kAuthPhase2_QueryName_RequestId].value
            response = form[kAuthPhase2_QueryName_Response].value
            initializationVector = form[kAuthPhase2_QueryName_InitializationVector].value   

            if gDebug:
                print "serverAuthResult called with these form values:"
                print "  requestId:            " + requestId
                print "  response:             " + response
                print "  initializationVector: " + initializationVector
                print

            # Find the key identifier associated with the incoming request, and use it
            # to get the server access key that we will use to decrypt the incoming response
            # and check it against the challenge originally provided.
            if requestId in gAuthRequests:
                # Remove the request from our dictionary so that we won't accidentally find it again
                authRequest = gAuthRequests.pop(requestId, None)

                # Get the services access key associated with the auth request, then decrypt the
                # response and compare it to the original challenge.
                helper = gValidAccessKeyHelpers[authRequest.getAccessKeyId()]
                decryptedChallenge = helper.decodeAndDecrypt(response, inIv=base64.b64decode(initializationVector))
                if gDebug:
                    print "decryptedChallenge:   " + base64.b64encode(decryptedChallenge)
                if decryptedChallenge == authRequest.getChallenge():
                    # Give the authenticated URL to the client. In a real server implementation, this
                    # would be a randomized URL, not static.
                    serverAuthResult.setNextUrl("http://" + str(TEST_SERVER_HOST_NAME) + ":" + str(THRIFT_PORT_NUMBER))

                    # Return a randomized session ID. Again, in the real server, this could be the same
                    # as the random component of the returned URL.
                    session = Session()
                    sessionId = session.getSessionId()
                    gSessions[sessionId] = session
                    serverAuthResult.setSessionId(sessionId)
                else:
                    serverAuthResult.setResultCode(str(AuthResultCode.kAuthResultCode_InvalidResponse))
                    serverAuthResult.setResultMessage("The specified response is not valid: " + response)
            else:
                serverAuthResult.setResultCode(str(AuthResultCode.kAuthResultCode_InvalidRequestId))
                serverAuthResult.setResultMessage("The specified requestId is not valid: " + requestId)
            print

        # Get the XML string that we'll return to the caller
        xml = serverAuthResult.getXml()
        if gDebug:
            print "About to provide this XML response to the client:"
            print
            print serverAuthResult.getXml(pretty=True)

        return xml

try:
    # Initialize the dictionary of valid server access keys that will work with this test
    # server.
    for curAccessKeyString in gValidAccessKeyStrings:
        helper = AccessKeyHelper.AccessKeyHelper(curAccessKeyString)
        gValidAccessKeyHelpers[helper.getAccessKeyIdentifier()] = helper

    # Initialize the dictionary of disabled server access keys that will work with this test
    # server.
    for curAccessKeyString in gDisabledAccessKeyStrings:
        helper = AccessKeyHelper.AccessKeyHelper(curAccessKeyString)
        gDisabledAccessKeyHelpers[helper.getAccessKeyIdentifier()] = helper

    # Start the Thrift server in a separate thread
    startThriftServer()

    # Create a web server and define the handler to manage incoming requests
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started http server on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    # Wait forever for incoming http requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server...'
    closeHttpServer(server)
    print '  Http server closed; Done processing control C'

if gThriftServer:
    print '  Calling the thrift server\'s server_close...'
    closeHttpServer(gThriftServer.httpd)
    print '  Thrift server closed'

if gThriftServerThread:
    print "Waiting for the thrift server thread to stop..."
    gThriftServerThread.join()

print "All servers stopped. Exiting..."

sys.exit(0)
```

startThriftServer() code is this

```
def startThriftServer():
    global gThriftServer
    global gThriftServerThread

    handler = EdenRemoteHandler()
    processor = EdenRemote.Processor(handler)
    pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
    gThriftServer = THttpServer.THttpServer(processor, (TEST_SERVER_HOST_NAME, THRIFT_PORT_NUMBER), pfactory)

    # Start the Thrift server in a separate thread
    gThriftServerThread = threading.Thread(target=serveFromThread, args=(gThriftServer, ))
    gThriftServerThread.start()
```

Comment: [Please help us to help you](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html)

Comment: @JensG Thank you. Actually since yesterday i am debugging it. Now i have update it please see. I hope now you can help me.

Comment: My guess would be that the server side does not use `TFramedTransport`. But it's only a guess. Can you show a bit of the python Thrift server setup?

Comment: @JensG I have added the server handler file. Please let me know if you want to know anything else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That#s what I'm looking for: `startThriftServer()` can we see that one? The handler code itself is not really useful, because it fails much earlier.

Comment: @JensG I have added the code of startThriftServer() in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo.

### Client code:

```
 $socket = new TSocket('localhost', 9090);
 $transport = new TFramedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
 $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
```

### Server code:

```
handler = EdenRemoteHandler()
processor = EdenRemote.Processor(handler)
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
gThriftServer = THttpServer.THttpServer(processor, ..., pfactory)
```

### So what's the problem with that?

The client uses `TFramedTransport` while the server does not. Although some server types do imply `TFramedTransport`, the `THttpServer` does not.

Solution is therefore

- either add `TFramedTransport` on the server side as well (recommended)
- or remove it from the client side if you can't change the server

If you have to pick the second case consider replacing `TFramedTransport` by `TBufferedTransport`, which is nearly as efficient, but does not have any impact on the wire format.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help. It was a great help for me. Even this API vendor did not understand the issue but you did. Again Thank you very much. I hope i can vote your answer more than once. :)

Comment: One more thing if i have to go with the second option then i have to use the THttpClient socket rather then TSocket as well.

Comment: Sounds as if it would make sense anyway to paír HTTP with HTTP. I noticed it, but then finallly forgot to ask if that is really by intention. So, yes, you're right about that point.

Comment: can you please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775782/thttpclient-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-400-bad-request Now i am trying to access the live server. And start getting this error. :(