# THttpClient failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, python, thrift

This is my code in Python to connect to the server which works very well.

```
transport = THttpClient.THttpClient(secureUrl)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
client = EdenRemote.Client(protocol)
transport.open()

print "calling openSession..."
client.openSession(sessionID, 1)
```

When I try to write the above code in PHP like this

```
$socket = new THttpClient($liveURL, 80, '', 'https');
$socket->setTimeoutSecs(50);
$transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
$client = new \edenremotephp\pub\EdenRemote\EdenRemoteClient($protocol);
$transport->open();
$client->openSession($result->sessionID, 1);
```

Then I got the following error

```
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => fopen(https://edenremote.paceap.com/EdenRemote/d11fbf20-ca24-45f0-b176-4a22e28907c5): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [file] => /home/abbas/www/local.edenremote.com/sdk/Thrift/Transport/THttpClient.php [line] => 207 )
```

Line 207 code is

```
public function flush() {
    // God, PHP really has some esoteric ways of doing simple things.
    $host = $this->host_.($this->port_ != 80 ? ':'.$this->port_ : '');

    $headers = array();
    $defaultHeaders = array('Host' => $host,
                            'Accept' => 'application/x-thrift',
                            'User-Agent' => 'PHP/THttpClient',
                            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-thrift',
                            'Content-Length' => TStringFuncFactory::create()->strlen($this->buf_));
    foreach (array_merge($defaultHeaders, $this->headers_) as $key => $value) {
        $headers[] = "$key: $value";
    }

    $options = array('method' => 'POST',
                     'header' => implode("\r\n", $headers),
                     'max_redirects' => 1,
                     'content' => $this->buf_);
    if ($this->timeout_ > 0) {
      $options['timeout'] = $this->timeout_;
    }
    $this->buf_ = '';

    $contextid = stream_context_create(array('http' => $options));
    $this->handle_ = @fopen($this->scheme_.'://'.$host.$this->uri_, 'r', false, $contextid);

    // Connect failed?
    if ($this->handle_ === FALSE) {
      $this->handle_ = null;
      $error = 'THttpClient: Could not connect to '.$host.$this->uri_;
      throw new TTransportException($error, TTransportException::NOT_OPEN);
    }
  }
```

Even I tried to change the https with the ssl. For transport even i tried

```
$transport = new TFramedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the issue with the THttpClient call. The first parameter should be the host and the uri should be in the 3rd parameter.

so the exact way to call it is

```
$result = json_decode(exec('./Authenticator.py'));
$liveURL = $result->secureUrl;
$liveURI = preg_replace('#^https?://edenremote.paceap.com#', '', rtrim($result->secureUrl,'/'));
$socket = new THttpClient('edenremote.paceap.com', 80, $liveURI, 'https');
$socket->setTimeoutSecs(50);
$transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
$client = new \edenremotephp\pub\EdenRemote\EdenRemoteClient($protocol);
$transport->open();
$client->openSession($result->sessionID, 1);
$isExist = $client->findUserByEmailAddress($result->sessionID, $account->primaryEmail);
var_dump($isExist);
$client->closeSession($result->sessionID);
echo 'Done';
```